# Why DeepEqual fails for [...]int{0} vs make([]int, 1, 1) in golang ? Is there an alternative?

Tags: go

I don't understand why DeepEqual fails in this case ?

Is there a builtin golang alternative without iterating each value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    a1 := [...]int{0}
    b1 := make([]int, 1, 1)
    fmt.Printf("Equal: %t %v %v\n", reflect.DeepEqual(a1, b1),a1,b1)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lqU3nBq6B3

Comment: If you use 2 slices, then they are equal: https://play.golang.org/p/x3NWCNsLAD

Comment: It fails because `a1` and `b1` don't have the same type. To see the expected result, call `reflect.DeepEqual(a1[:], b1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't even the same type:

```
a1 := [...]int{0}       // *array*, equivalent to [1]int{0}
b1 := make([]int, 1, 1) // *slice*, equivalent to []int{0}

// Equal: false - because they're different types!
fmt.Printf("Equal: %t (types: %T vs %T)\n", reflect.DeepEqual(a1, b1), a1, b1)
// But, if we take a slice of the array, they're comparable:
fmt.Printf("Equal: %t (types: %T vs %T)\n", reflect.DeepEqual(a1[:], b1), a1[:], b1)
```

Playground demonstration: https://play.golang.org/p/B77iKS8gQd

The declarations are explained in [the spec section on composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). Slicing arrays is covered in [the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) and [the spec section on slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions).